# SQL query to group different strings of words together that both share at least two of the same words

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a feature that's similar to what Google News does - groups headlines together based on how similar they are.

I thought I would do this by grouping headlines together where headlines share a minimum number of the same word.

Is there a simple SQL query that would look at strings of text and then group them together in this manner?

In my query I'd be grouping article titles together.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't going to be a simple SQL query to do this.  You'll need to decide how you are analyzing the words in the headlines, and which words are stop words, and a variety of other issues.  Once you have a way to do that analysis, then the grouping is probably simple - but getting to the point where you have the words properly organized is going to take the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would explode headlines' each words separately, and save them like "tags" and write a query which displays other articles sharing common tags. You both solve your question, and have a tag system. win-win.

Comment: Might want to ignore common or small words like the and a

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how to do that in SQL itself, but that will be done with your scripting language. I would first trim unwanted characters like - , . " etc. , then start exploding. E.g: PHP has a nice function called explode() http://php.net/explode . you can explode them, and use in_array() http://php.net/in_array to check whether the each part of the exploded characters is in your $unwanted_words array (to do what Jason mentioned above), then insert into table. After that you can easily join your articles (or whatever that is) table with your tags table and show similar headlines.